# React-Native (Android only) - TypeError: Network request failed

Tags: android, react-native, fetch-api

I use React Native and I want to fetch data from my API. My API is hosted externally.
My API is made using [ExpressJS](https://expressjs.com/).

To make HTTP requests (GET and POST requests) the [React Native Fetch](https://reactnative.dev/docs/network) is implemented

The error `TypeError: Network request failed` is thrown whenever trying to call the API (GET or POST, I don't use PUT or others).

The error does **not** occur in the following environments:

1. Android (local development, using Expo Go)
2. iOS (local development, using Expo Go)
3. iOS (published on the app store)

The error only occurs in the production app, which is visible in the Google Play Store.

I use [Sentry](https://sentry.io) to log any errors that occur on the client side.

In here the error is visible.
[Screenshot of error in Sentry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zewkk.png)

Inside of my API server I use a function to write errors to a log file.

Some of the customers of our company had contact us regarding this issue.

My following attempts did not solve the issue:

- Restart the API service.
- Remove `app.use(cors());` from my Express file of where the Express app is created.
- Try to call one of my other API endpoints.
- View the error logs in my server side. -> The endpoint never seems to be called.
- Installed the app on BlueStacks to see if the error also occurs there -> Yes, error occurs here.
- Ask my co-worker for his Android phone to test the app to see if the error occurs there -> Yes, error occurs here.
- Validate the correct version is published in the Google Play Store. -> Yes, version is correct.
- Try to publish a new version with the same code. -> Did not resolve the issue.
- Search Google to find a possible fix.

Comment: It might be the issue that your endpoint is not encrypted.

Comment: You say 'that your endpoint is not encrypted'.

Do you mean I (could possibly) need https instead of http? 
I call my API with http://

Or what else do you mean with my endpoint not being encrypted?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean.
You have to allow ```usesCleartextTraffic``` (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element)

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I'm seeing a very similar thing. On startup my RN does a few calls using fetch (I'm not using expo). Only in my Android PRD app I see (in sentry) the "TypeError: Network request failed" failure, causing problems in my app down stream. This never happens on iOS. My connections are all over HTTPS.. clueless what is going on. After a few minutes a user can restart the app as normal.

Answer (score -1):

1. Edit `AndroidManifest.xml` in the project Folder (Name\android\app\src\main)
2. Add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` into
   `<application...>` and `<activity...>`, e.g.:

   `<application android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">`

   `<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"  android:screenOrientation="portrait">`

   [image: example image]