# Expo Issue: Unable to make an HTTP request

Tags: typescript, react-native, axios, request, expo

I have a strange problem.
I've created an expo app using axios to make a simple request to an API, and everything works fine with Expo Go, but once the app is built with EAS, I get an error: no request is sent from the app (I was able to check this with an analysis proxy). In fact, I've even rebuilt the app several times and tried using fetch, but nothing happens, always the same error, and above all, impossible to know which one.
I think the solution is quite simple, or that there's simply something missing, but what? it's impossible to know.
The request is just a basic GET request to an HTTP server, and worked perfectly in the browser and with node.

Here is the code with the issue:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import EditScreenInfo from '../../components/EditScreenInfo';
import { Text, View } from '../../components/Themed';

import { helloWorld } from '../../utils/api';

const TabTwoScreen = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        // helloWorld()
        //  .then(({ data }) => alert(data))
        //  .catch(() => alert("An unkown error has occured"))

        fetch('http://192.168.1.27:1700/hello-world')
            .then(data => data.text())
            .then(data => alert(data))
            .catch(() => alert("An unknown error has occured"));
    });

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Tab Two</Text>
            <View style={styles.separator} lightColor="#eee" darkColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.1)" />
            <EditScreenInfo path="app/(tabs)/two.tsx" />
        </View>
    );
}

export default TabTwoScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    separator: {
        marginVertical: 30,
        height: 1,
        width: '80%',
    },
});
```

And here you get my `eas.json` (I build with this command: `eas build --profile preview -p android`)

```json
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 5.9.3"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

I tested building an old app with an old version of Expo and fetch and axios worked perfectly with the same API (the app was working on expo@47 and the new app with expo@49).

Comment: Maybe this is related to this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77679351/react-native-android-only-typeerror-network-request-failed#comment136977763_77679351

Android is no longer allowed to request an http endpoints.

Comment: @MichaelBahl it was that! Thanks, I just forget to try with HTTPS...thanks again!