# React Native fetch() Network Request Failed only on android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, fetch-api

I'm working on an application with React Native, before yesterday, everything was working fine (since 2 years) and yesterday, it broke and we can't understand why.

We're using some fetch in our application (which looks like the one below), and it worked fine.

Yesterday, around 6pm, all of our android phone (ours and the one of our users) stopped being able to do those fetch. We were not doing any changes on the code at this time, no push, no edit, no changes in the server.

We've been searching the cause all day, can't find it, android phone just can't communicate with our server anymore (it's an https for those wondering).

We can fetch url like https://google.com but cannot fetch any url from our domain from the app https://xxxxxx.com (those same url could be accessed by the same android phone via chrome / firefox and works fine)

```
async function Request_Async(data = {}, url = Config.SERVER_URL, method = 'POST', headers = defaultHeaders) {
    let status = null;
    let content = null;

    const header = {
        method: method,
        headers: headers,
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    };

    try {
        const request = await fetch(url, header);
        status = request.status;
        if (request.status === 200) {
            content = await request.json();
        } else {
            content = { error: request.statusText };
        }
    } catch (err) {
        status = 1;
        content = { error: err };
    }

    return new ReqResponse(status, content);
}
```

Comment: Use a valid ssl certificate or use ```useClearTraffic``` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77679351/react-native-android-only-typeerror-network-request-failed#comment136977763_77679351)

Comment: I'm not sure of what you mean by using a valid ssl certificate ? What was it working before and not now anymore ?

Comment: UPDATE : after some time, we did nothing, all of our android works fine and all iOS have the same problem.

Comment: You might use an ssl certifícate which expired?